# When does $\text{Aut}(G)$ act transitively on $n$-tuples of generators of $G$ whose product is 1?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a finite group. When does the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(G)$ act transitively on a subset of $n$-tuples of generators of $G$ that multiply to 1?

I'm interested in this question in relation to the triangle groups. For example, when $G=\text{PSL}(2,7)$, there are exactly 336 triples of generators of orders 2, 3, and 7 which multiply to 1. In this case $\text{Aut}(G)=\text{PGL}(2,7)$ and so $|\text{Aut}(G)|=|\text{PGL}(2,7)|=336$. In other cases $|\text{Aut}(G)|$ divides the number of triples. Is the action still transitive in these cases?

Comment: You seem to be talking about $n$-tuples of generators that obey some set of relations rather than all $n$-tuples. At the moment your question is too broad and you need to ask something more specific. Which other cases are you thinking of?

Comment: You're right. I'm interested in $n$-tuples of generators whose product is 1. Here are some other examples I'm thinking of. For PSL(2,11), there are precisely 1320=|PGL(2,11)| triples of generators with g1, g2, g3 of orders 2, 3, 11 and 2, 6, 11 that multiply to 1. In PSL(2,17), if we count the number of generator triples of three given orders multiplying to 1, we never get exactly |PGL(2,17)|, but we do get a multiple.

Comment: In your comment you mention generators with given orders, but you don't mention "given orders" in your question. In any case, if the number of such triples is more than $|{\rm Aut}(G)|$ then ${\rm Aut}(G)$ obviously cannot act transitively on them.  But it obviously does act transitively on some subset of them. What exactly are you asking?